# Linq to entity order by sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm doing some tests with `EF` and `Linq to entities` to try and improve my application performance.

I just notice something odd (to me) that I can't explain and also can't really tell if incurs considerable overhead.

Here's my linq:

```
var result = from n in query
        orderby n.PersonId
        select new
        {
            id = n.Id,
            appointmentId = n.AppointmentId,
            message = n.Message,
            wasRead = n.Read,
            canDismiss = (n.Appointment.Status != AppointmentStatus.Waiting),
            date = n.IssueDateUtc
        };
```

This is the generated sql:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[AppointmentId] AS [AppointmentId], 
    [Project1].[Message] AS [Message], 
    [Project1].[Read] AS [Read], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[IssueDateUtc] AS [IssueDateUtc]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Read] AS [Read], 
        [Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], 
        [Extent1].[IssueDateUtc] AS [IssueDateUtc], 
        [Extent1].[AppointmentId] AS [AppointmentId], 
        [Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
        CASE WHEN ( NOT ((1 = [Extent2].[Status]) AND ([Extent2].[Status] IS NOT NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN (1 = [Extent2].[Status]) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Notification] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Appointment] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AppointmentId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE [Extent1].[PersonId] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Project1]
    **ORDER BY [Project1].[PersonId] ASC**
```

I don't understand the need to kind of group the result in another projection (`Project1`) whilst this seems to work just fine:

```
SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Read] AS [Read], 
        [Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], 
        [Extent1].[IssueDateUtc] AS [IssueDateUtc], 
        [Extent1].[AppointmentId] AS [AppointmentId], 
        [Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
        CASE WHEN ( NOT ((1 = [Extent2].[Status]) AND ([Extent2].[Status] IS NOT NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN (1 = [Extent2].[Status]) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Notification] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Appointment] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AppointmentId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE [Extent1].[PersonId] = @p__linq__0
        **ORDER BY [Extent1].[PersonId] ASC**
```

I found a considerable amount of questionable sql generated by both ef and linq and I'm starting to wonder if I wasn't better off just writing raw sqls.

Question is: is the generated sql extra bits of code something to be worried about? Why is that projection necessary?

**Edit to add a new linq**

As mentioned in the comments, maybe the verbose was caused by subsequent queries being run. I rewrote the linq to use only one query object, and the result is still the same:

```
dbSet.Where(n => n.PersonId == id).Select(n => new
            {
                Id = n.Id,
                AppointmentId = n.AppointmentId,
                Message = n.Message,
                Read = n.Read,
                CanBeDismissed = (n.Appointment.Status != AppointmentStatus.Waiting),
                IssueDate = n.IssueDateUtc
            }).OrderBy(n => n.Id).ToList();
```

**Execution plan (same for both `sqls`)**

[image: actual execution plan]

**Edit 2**

Just got this query from a simple count.

```
dbSet.Count(x => x.Id == 1 && x.Read == false);

SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Notification] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[PersonId] = 19) AND (0 = [Extent1].[Read])
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Expected:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Notification] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[PersonId] = 19) AND (0 = [Extent1].[Read])
```

I don't get where all this wrappers are coming from and why.

Comment: I suppose `query` is another LINQ-to-SQL query, and that is what you see nested inside the projection. It's exactly what you are doing with LINQ. If you want to get rid of it, just add the `OrderBy` and `Select` to whatever is `query`. But if using subsequent LINQ queries makes your code cleaner, don't worry ... projection have a minimal overhead, if any. Compare the execution plan if in doubt. But if you see performance issues, it will sure not be caused by that projection.

Comment: And about your concern about the queries LINQ-to-SQL generates ... I find Linq-to-SQL producing excellent (yet often verbose) SQL queries, even more in complex scenarios. I'd say it's better than what most programmers would achieve. But of course it also requires well written LINQ queries. So it's good that you double check the generated SQL ... but in general, don't worry, LINQ in general makes very good choices for when to use joins, cross applys or whatever performs best, I actually often learned something new from looking at LINQ's generated SQL ;)

Comment: Im always learning something new too. I just worry because I havent studied much about sgdb, and my product is growing, and now that Im taking the time to analyse the db accesses Im seeing quite terrible code, and just rewriting the expressions I was able to boost performance in about 60%. Anyway, I rewrote the linq using only one query and the result was the same. I will add it to the question, please check it out. I think the extra code is generated because of the anonymous type being used.

Comment: Don't worry about the projection, it's not bad (performing) SQL just a bit verbose ... try executing both queries in SQL Server Management Studio and activate the execution plan and statistics ... you'll see the outcome will be almost identical. As to how to get rid of the projection anyhow, I get back to you tomorrow with a sample if no one else jumps in as I have to leave now. But let me know what exactly the `where` inside `dbSet.Where()` does.

Comment: I added the the `where` in the code (`n => n.PersonId == id`). Thanks.

Comment: The anonymous type is not the issue ... it's that you execute the orderby after you select the results already. Try moving the orderby before the select.

Comment: Added actual execution plan to the question. Moving the orderby didnt change anything.

Comment: What's the problem with the query? Orderby is gonna be done at the end anyway by SQL Server. What takes longer in the query are the index scan and index seek. They have nothing to do with the "nested" select. Have you compared the query plan of both your SQL Statement?

Comment: @GabrielGM not a problem exactly, but the issue in question is the extra projection (Project1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put together a small sample project on my machine. What acutally causes the projection in your first sample is your conditional calculation of the CanBeDismissed field, resulting in a `CASE WHEN` in SQL. If you leave this out, Entity Framework won't do an additional projection.

So with an conditional check:

```
db.Notifications
    .Where(n => n.AppointmentId == 1)
    .OrderBy(n => n.Id)
    .Select(n => new
    {
        Id = n.Id,
        Message = n.Message,
        HasMessage = n.Message != null
    }).ToList();
```

The SQL produced is:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[Message] AS [Message], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Message] IS NOT NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Notifications] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[AppointmentId]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC
```

Let me add the resulting execution plan for later reference:

[image: Execution plan with projection]

If you leave it out:

```
db.Notifications
    .Where(n => n.AppointmentId == 1)
    .OrderBy(n => n.Id)
    .Select(n => new
    {
        Id = n.Id,
        Message = n.Message
    }).ToList();
```

No projection is done by EF:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Message] AS [Message]
    FROM [dbo].[Notifications] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[AppointmentId]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
```

So this is the why. Same applies to your `count` sample: if there is any grouping happening, EF will add an additional projection which makes the query more verbose. But the important part is, as discussed in the comments to your question, **it won't hurt performance**, there is no need to worry about this additional projection.

Let me proof this by now adding the execution plan of the following query, where I have just removed the pojection from the first query and moved the orderby to the inner query:

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Message] IS NOT NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Notifications] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[AppointmentId]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
```

[image: Execution plan wihtout projection]

It's exactly the same - there is no additional task added and the cost distribution remains the same. The SQL Query Optimizer will optimize such projecitons away just nicely.

So again, don't worry about projections - they won't hurt you, while I agree they seem and are sometimes unnecessarily verbose. But here are two things that might help you:

**Performance issues:**

First, if you are experiencing performance issues with your query, look at why there happens a `Clustered Index Scan` in the execution plan you posted. This is not always a sign for some indexing issues, but it is very often. Your problems might root here.

**Get rid of unneccesary projections:**

If you still want to get rid of those projections in all (or at least more) cases, there is Entity Framework Core 1.0 - it actually produces even nicer SQL than EF 6. It might be worth considering migrating to it, yet be aware that it does not come with all features that EF 6 does, so it might not be an option if you are using features that EF Core 1.0 does not offer. But it will work with the full .NET Framework 4.x!

Here's an example what EF Core 1.0 produces when I execute the first LINQ statement of my answer:

```
SELECT [n].[Id], [n].[Message], CASE
    WHEN [n].[Message] IS NULL
    THEN CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT)
END
FROM [Notifications] AS [n]
WHERE ([n].[Id] = 1) AND ([n].[Id] = 1)
ORDER BY [n].[Id]
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I think the index scan happens because every row must be checked to see whether its fk column is X or not. After this condition is resolved, you can see on the execution plan I posted it seems that the db does an index seek to grab the row with id X to perform the join. I *think* this is right, not sure though.
Still, it is weird that EF deems necessary to add an extra projection in some cases.